# Difficulty understanding Linear maps between vector spaces as $(1,1)$ tensors on the target vector space

Tags: linear-transformations, tensors, multilinear-algebra

In Nakahara's book "Geometry, Topology, and Physics" there is an exercise that asks to show that if $f$ is a Linear Map between vector spaces: $f: V \rightarrow W$ then it is a tensor of type $(1, 1)$.

The exercise is fairly simple because there isn't a lot of ways to "force" $f$ to fit this definition, clearly for $v \in V$ we have $f(v) \in W$ and hence $f(v)$ is a type $(1,0)$ tensor on $W$. So, by virtue of this we can go on to say that since $f(v)$ acts on a co-vector $\omega \in W^{\ast}$ we have a map that takes pairs of the form $(\omega, f(v))$ to some underlying field $K$ and hence establish that $f$ is a $(1, 1)$ tensor.

My difficulty with this first and foremost, is that $f$ is not guaranteed to be surjective on $W$, since it is only said to be a Linear Map and nothing further. So can it be a proper Tensor on $W$ at all in such a case?

A secondary problem is how contrived it appears to force $f$ to fit this definition, and I am not sure why and where is it useful to do this. I'll be glad if someone can help me to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of finite dimensions and if you have basis
$$V={\rm span}\{b_1,...,b_n\},$$
$$W={\rm span}\{c_1,...,c_m\},$$
then one defines
$L_{f\otimes w}:V\to W$
via $$L_{f\otimes w}x=f(x)w,$$
where $V^*={\rm span}\{\beta^1,...,\beta^n\}$ is the dual of $V$ and so $\beta^k(b_j)=\delta^k_j$.

That transformation is linear and the element $f\otimes w$ is in
$V^*\otimes W$.

The task of checking that $L:V^*\otimes W \to \hom(V,W)$, mapping
$$f\otimes w\mapsto L_{f\otimes w},$$
is a vector spaces isomorphism, would be a routine.

**Observation:**

The elements $\beta^k\otimes c_j$ serve to generate
$V^*\otimes W$.

Comment: If I read your answer correctly, I understand that what you showed is that in fact $f$ is a map that can be written as $f: V \times W^{\star} \rightarrow K$ ? So it is in fact a tensor on the product vector space of $V$ and $W$, not on $W$ alone as I assumed?

Comment: the map is $$V^*\otimes W\stackrel{L}\to\hom (V,W),$$ if you would use $f$ as an element of   $V^*$. But if you use it as in your original post is $V\stackrel{f}\to W$ and linear.

Comment: The space $V^*\otimes W$ is a tensor space of rank $(1,1)$: one-covariant by $V^*$ and one contra-variant for $W$.

Comment: Okay, but if I understand correctly, the rank $(1,1)$ tensor is an *element* of that space. So it is a mapping which is an element of the space you wrote: $V^{\star} \otimes W$ and as such, it takes elements from $V \times W^{\star}$ to $K$, correct? (where in the last expression I am using $\times$ as cartesian product, not tensor product).

Comment: An elements in $V^*\otimes W$ are bi-indexed linear combinations $C_s{}^t\beta^s\otimes c_t$ that can be considered as a **bilinear** maps $V\times W^*\to \mathbb K$ defined by $$C_s{}^t\beta^s\otimes c_t(v, g)=C_s{}^t\beta^s(v)g(c_t).$$

Comment: Okay, but to take that back to the original question... is it true that $f$ can be shown to be an element of this space: $V^{\star}\otimes W$ and therefore a rank $(1,1)$ tensor?

Comment: Yes, but call it $F$ and is because any $F\in\hom(V,W)$ can be considered as a matrix which are linear combinations of the **elementary matrices** associated to $\beta^i\otimes c_j$

Comment: Okay. The only thing that is still a bit surprising is that one can consider that a proper *tensor* from the definition of a tensor, it appears that only a single vector space and its dual are involved in the domain...

Comment: all I'd said could be particularized to $V=W$.

Comment: Of course. My question is only in this case here where $V \neq W$ is it still a tensor?

Comment: Definitely yes!

Comment: Thank you very much